# Open .bin file then put its value on the textbox?

Tags: .net, vb.net, binary

Im migrating from vb6 to vb.net. Can please someone explain how to do this action: Open .bin file - then put a value of it on textbox or richtextbox or listbox, the point is that i will need to be able to send that value through UART 
.Bin file contains:
[Bin file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FntKd.png)

Any help appreciate it, Thanks.
i trying like this:

```
 Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' Get the file name.
    Dim input As New FileStream("feu04_7952_eeprom.bin", FileMode.Open)
    Dim reader As New BinaryReader(input)
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    bytes = reader.ReadBytes(CInt(input.Length))
    TextBox3.Text = bytes
End Sub
```

Comment: Look into the [`BinaryReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: I tried with it, but the problem is that TetxtBox.Text requires string values, as BinaryReady uses bytes value.

Comment: i updataed the code with BInaryRead sample

Comment: A `BinaryReader` does not "use bytes values". The point of a `BinaryReader` is that it reads bytes from a file and returns a .NET object of the specified type. If you call `ReadBytes` then you get a `Byte` array but you can call `ReadString` then you get a `String`. The thing is, the text has to be stored in a specific way in the file to be read that way. You haven't actually told us what the file contains so we can't tell you how to read it. A BIN file generally contains a binary representation of arbitrary data. The best way to read it depends on how it was written. There's no one way.

Comment: You are right, my fault, the .bin contains 512 bytes data, i updated with picture of opened .bin how it looks

Comment: That's useless without our know what that 512 bytes represents.  It could be anything for all we know.

Comment: check the picture below please, "bin file".  Origianally that dump was written from ic's eeprom, and the prog that was written it stores data in file like 1 byte "space" 1 byte "space" etc

Comment: Your picture is useless.  If you can't explain what the data actually represents then we can't tell you how to read it.  It's that simple.

Comment: 512 bytes written in hex, 1 byte (space) 1 byte (space) 1 byte (space). What can i  add? That's all info about that storage. I dont know what you mean by "what data represents"

Comment: I could have some bytes that represent an IP address. I know they're an IP but to everyone else it's garbage. What does your 512 bytes of data actually tell you?

Comment: It's microcontroller eeprom's data.

Comment: @OneFineDay in my experience, `BinaryReader` is almost never the right choice for reading *arbitrary* (meaning: external) binary files. It is fine when paired with it's co-conspirator, `BinaryWriter` - since they share all the same conventions, but for anything else: frankly, `Stream` / `Span<byte>` / `BinaryPrimitives`

Comment: @Woods I don't see anything that looks like "1 byte (space) 1 byte (space) 1 byte (space)" in that image; if you just want the raw bytes: `File.ReadAllBytes(path)`. If you want to *decode* them into something meaningful, you really need to protocol specification. You say you want to "put a value of it on textbox or richtextbox or listbox" - well: what value, and where in that file is it? Note: if you just want the *hex*, that's easy enough.